# Atribuição de Arrays em Java

Tags: java, array, string, comparação

Eu possuo dois Arrays de Strings e tenho que compará-los. Após a comparação eu devo atribuir os valores repetidos em outro Array.
Meu problemas é que eu desejo atribuir **apenas** as Strings **repetidas** sem as Strings que não se repetem.

Código:

```
//ARRAYS PARA COMPARAR:

String nomes[] = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};  
String comparar[] = {"Juliana", "Pedro", "Ana", "Luiz"};
String res[] = {};

//REALIZA A LEITURA DO ARRAY MAIOR:
for(String x : nomes){
    System.out.println("X : " + x);

    //SE HÁ STRING DO ARRAY MENOR NO MAIOR:
    if(nomes[0].equals(comparar[1])){
        //COPIA AS STRINGS PARA OUTRO ARRAY:
        res = comparar;       //***Problema***
    }

}

//MOSTRA AS STRINGS COPIADAS:
    for(String a : res){
        System.out.println("RES: " + a);
    }
}
```

A atribuição de Arrays `res = comparar;` "copia" todos os elementos do array.
Como posso copiar apenas os repetidos?

Comment: Peço desculpas pelos erros de edição e muito obrigado pelas alterações Denis Rudnei de Souza.

Comment: Obrigado. Sobre as [edições](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) que fiz

Comment: **Obs:** Caso deseje notificar alguém, pode colocar um `@` na frente do nome, assim `@Denis Rudnei de Souza`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer simplesmente:

```
String nomes[] = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};  
String comparar[] = {"Juliana", "Pedro", "Ana", "Luiz"};

Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(nomes));
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(comparar));
s1.retainAll(s2);

String[] res = s1.toArray(new String[s1.size()]);

for(String r : res) 
    System.out.println(r);
```

---

Saída:

> `Ana`
>   `Pedro`

---

Baseado [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863345/7394442) resposta.

Comment: Com Guava `Set<T> set = Sets.newHashSet(nomes);`, no Java 8 `Arrays.stream(nomes).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Igor Venturelli. Vou estudar mais sobre Set e HashSet. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @Alan.O.S legal! Fico feliz por ter ajudado. Se funcionou, poderia marcar como solução, por favor?

Comment: Eu me esqueci de marcar. Obrigado novamente!

Answer (score 2):

Como isso parece um exercício, lá vai apenas uma ideia pra ti. Acredito que o algoritmo que você busca, usando apenas arrays, é similar á:

1. [Enquanto o **Array1** possuir valores] Obtêm um valor **x** do **Array1** (você o fez no primeiro **for**)
2. [Enquanto o **Array2** possuir valores] Obtêm um valor do **Array2** (outro **for** similar ao primeiro) comparando-o com o valor **x** e...

   - A) Se for igual, adiciona o valor no ArrayResultado (seu Array res).
   - B) Caso negativo, bem, não faça nada.

Ao fim desta computação, você deve obter o resultado que busca (que deve ser "Pedro" e "Ana").

```
X : Pedro
X : Diego
X : Ana
X : Carlos
RES: Pedro
RES: Ana
```

Um detalhe: tome cuidado com sua declaração do Array resultado `String[] res = {}`. Quando você declara um array desta forma, você está efetivamente criando um array com zero posições, o que irá te causar problemas ao tentar atribuir um valor.

Minha sugestão para você é declarar desta forma:

```
String res[] = new String[nomes.length];
```

Fazendo isto, mesmo que todos os nomes do Array nomes estejam no Array de comparação, você não terá problemas.

## Edição

Inicialmente, considerei que seria melhor não falar sobre isso mas, pensando melhor, acho útil deixar aqui um comentário com relação à "cópia" de arrays (conforme citado na questão), por completude.

Quando atribuímos um Array à outro, em Java, seus valores não são copiados - o que acontece é uma cópia da **referência** do Array. Após esta operação, ambas as variáveis representam efetivamente o mesmo Array.

Para mais informações, [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201707170133197123158) entrada do Stackoverflow EN, pode ser útil (se houver uma em PT que alguém conheça, editar). Um exemplo comentado:

```
public static void passagemDeReferencia() {
    String[] array1 = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};
    String[] array2 = array1; // Isto passa uma referência do Array - não é uma cópia

    // Ambos arrays são idênticos, conforme visto comparando a primeira posição.
    System.out.println("array1[0] == array2[0]: " + array1[0].equals(array2[0]));
    System.out.println("array1[0]: " + array1[0]);
    System.out.println("array2[0]: " + array2[0]);
    // array1[0] == array2[0]: true
    // array1[0]: Pedro
    // array2[0]: Pedro

    // Alterar qualquer posição do array2, irá alterar o array1.
    array2[0] = "Miguel"; 
    System.out.println("array1[0] == array2[0]: " + array1[0].equals(array2[0]));
    System.out.println("array1[0]: " + array1[0]);
    System.out.println("array2[0]: " + array2[0]);
    // array1[0] == array2[0]: true
    // array1[0]: Miguel
    // array2[0]: Miguel

    // Assim como alterar qualquer posição de array1, irá alterar o array2.
    array1[0] = "Pedro"; 
    System.out.println("array1[0] == array2[0]: " + array1[0].equals(array2[0]));
    System.out.println("array1[0]: " + array1[0]);
    System.out.println("array2[0]: " + array2[0]);
    // array1[0] == array2[0]: true
    // array1[0]: Pedro
    // array2[0]: Pedro
}
```

Para necessidades de cópia, deve-se usar um Array Copy.

```
public static void copiandoArrays() {
    String[] array1 = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};
    String[] array2 = new String[array1.length];
    System.arraycopy(array1, 0, array2, 0, array1.length); // Este método efetua uma cõpia do array
    // Mais código
}
```

Comment: Entendi a sua lógica para o código Miguel, vou implementá-la.
Obrigado pela sugestão da declaração do Array Resultado.

Muito obrigado Miguel Fontes!

Answer (score 0):

Modifiquei seu código e acredito que encontrei a solução:

```
String nomes[] = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};  
        String comparar[] = {"Juliana", "Pedro", "Ana", "Luiz"};
        ArrayList<String> res= new ArrayList<String>();

//REALIZA A LEITURA DO ARRAY MAIOR:
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nomes.length;i++){
            String nome=nomes[i];
            System.out.println("X : " + nome);

            //SE HÁ STRING DO ARRAY MENOR NO MAIOR:
            for(String y :comparar){
                if(y.equals(nome))
                {
                    res.add(nome);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),nome,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

              }}
```

Caso eu não tenha entendido a sua questão, por favor, adicione um comentário.

Answer (score 0):

Percebo que atualizou a sua pergunta e não aceitou nenhuma Resposta, o que me leva a crer que você quer que o "resultado" seja um Array string não um Array List String. Veja esta modificação e me diga o que achou:

```
String nomes[] = {"Pedro", "Diego", "Ana", "Carlos"};  
        String comparar[] = {"Juliana", "Pedro", "Ana", "Luiz"};
        String res[] = {};
        ArrayList<String> repetidos= new ArrayList<String>();

        //REALIZA A LEITURA DO ARRAY MAIOR:
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nomes.length;i++)
        {
            String nome=nomes[i];
            System.out.println("X : " + nome);

            //SE HÁ STRING DO ARRAY MENOR NO MAIOR:
            for (String y :comparar)
            {
                if (y.equals(nome))
                {
                    repetidos.add(nome);
                }
            }
        }

        //ADICIONA ARRAY LIST PARA ARRAY STRING
        res = new String[repetidos.size()];

        for (int i = 0;i < repetidos.size();i++)
        {
            res[i] = repetidos.get(i);
        }
        //MOSTRA AS STRINGS COPIADAS:
        for(String a : res){
            System.out.println("RES: " + a);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),a+" Tamanho "+res.length,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Jefferson! Ficou muito claro a leitura e interpretação do seu código. Muito Obrigado.

Comment: De nada, fico feliz em ajudar